# Python importação de módulos próprios erro

Tags: python, pyside

Estou com problemas na importação dos módulos no meu projeto após criar arquivo executável. Fiz um pequeno projeto com uma interface gráfica para cadastro de clientes porém ao tentar abrir o arquivo executável gera um erro: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cadastro'

Ao executar o programa pelo editor (PyCharm) funciona perfeitamente, o erro acontece apenas quando tento executar pelo arquivo .exe.

Segue a estrutura do projeto:

```
Interfaces Gráficas/    
  Sistema de Cadastro/
      __init__.py
      cadastro.py
      cadastro.ui
      database.py
      icone.ico
      icones.qrc
      icones_rc.py
      sistema.py
      system.db
```

Início do código com as importações feitas:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QTableWidgetItem)
from cadastro import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from database import DataBase
import pandas as pd

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Sistema de Cadastro de Pessoas/Clientes")
        appIcon = QIcon()
        self.setWindowIcon(appIcon)
```

O comando para gerar o arquivo executável foi:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icone.ico sistema.py
```

Comment: Isso (`__init.py__`) foi erro de digitação? O certo seria `__init__.py`. Porém, qual versão de Python está usando?

Comment: Não havia percebido esse erro de digitação do __init__.py vou arrumar. A versão do python é a 3.10.6

Comment: O que vou dizer é puro **achismo**, o erro é que ao criar um executável, o executável não é capaz de fazer o import dos outros arquivos por não encontrar eles ou por não conseguir ler arquivos python

Comment: Adicione o parâmetro `paths` ao pyinstaller: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --paths path\to\venv\Lib\site-packages --windowed sistema.py`

Answer (score -1):

Consegui de outra maneira que achei aqui no Stack Overflow, criei uma pasta Lib dentro do diretório onde está o projeto e coloquei todos os arquivos .py usados no projetos dentro dela e gerei o executável, funcionou.

A estrutura do projeto ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
Interfaces Gráficas/    
  Sistema de Cadastro/
      __init__.py
      cadastro.ui
      icones.qrc
  Lib/
      cadastro.py
      database.py
      icones_rc.py
      sistema.py
      icone.ico
      system.db
```

Portanto criei o executável no terminar do pycharm com o mesmo comando:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icone.ico sistema.py
```

mas dentro da nova pasta Lib

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).